# How to change encryption algorithm for private key file using OpenSSH 5.3

Tags: linux, ssh, security, encryption, openssh

Using `ssh-keygen`, I need to generate a SSH private key file where the encryption algorithm used when using a passphrase is AES-128 with CBC mode.

I know this is the default for OpenSSH >= 5.4 as per the [release notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) where they mention:

> Passphrase-protected SSH protocol 2 private keys are now protected
>      with AES-128 instead of 3DES. This applied to newly-generated keys
>      as well as keys that are reencrypted (e.g. by changing their
>      passphrase).

However, my requirement is to use this encryption algorithm with OpenSSH 5.3p1 (I cannot change the OpenSSH version).

How can I change the encryption algorithm to AES-128 without upgrading to OpenSSH 5.4 or newer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` has no options to specify the passphrase encryption, so you cannot simply make the old `ssh-keygen` behave like the new version by changing a configuration file or giving an option to it, but you can use **OpenSSL** to generate or convert the keys.

### Conversion

Assuming your key is RSA

```
openssl rsa -aes128 -in <3des_protected> -out <aes128_protected>
```

will convert `3des_protected` key in an AES128 one. It will ask for a passphrase three times: once for reading the old key, twice to set the new one.

### Creation

First create the private part

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out <newkey>
```

then change its permission so that ssh doesn't complain with `chmod 600 <newkey>`

The public key is then derived from the private one by issuing

```
ssh-keygen -e -f newkey > newkey.pub
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to convert a PuTTy Keygen private key export from 3DES to AES, so that I could use it with the SSH key agent in KeePassXC. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to regenerate my old private key with the `openssl` command, but now the key comment is `id_rsa`. Is there a way to set the key comment with the `openssl` command?

Comment: @Pablo you can invoke `ssh-keygen -c`  and follow the instructions. I'm not aware of a solution using `openssl`